# c# .net tasks/threading console application

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, console-application

I have a console app which moves files. It initially moved files ine by one. I then started to explore multithreading in order to move all files at once. I have found that I must put a console.read() call after each foreach loop in order to keep the tasks running. Without this the app closes. With this approach, the app remains open even when completed. Doeas anybody have any suggestions as to how to get around this issue;

```
        foreach (string file in files)
        {

            Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { MoveFiles(file, str); });

        }

        Console.Read();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Paralell.Foreach` instead of `foreach`. It is a *blocking* call.

```
Parallel.ForEach(files, file =>
{
     MoveFiles(file, str);
});
```

BTW: It is better than starting **N** tasks (suppose there are 10K files) at once and then waiting to finish all of them (by*Task.WaitAll*)

Comment: Thanks everyone. Managed to get the above working just fine.

Answer (score 1):

`StartNew()` actually returns a `Task` object. You can save all these objects in a List and instead of `Console.Read();` do a `Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());`.

That last call will wait for the tasks to finish. After they are finished, your program will close.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. Although I have tried both of the above suggestions the application works differently. The foreach which I posted above works on all files in all folders in parallel. The paralell.foreach and task.waitall methods do not appear to allow the app to work in this way?

Comment: Yes, as @yper said, parallel foreach is a *blocking* call.